# Transmitting UDP packages with source address 0.0.0.0

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

In linux, how can I transmit an UDP packet using 0.0.0.0 as source address.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in dst, src;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int sock, tmp;
    char payload[128];

    memset(payload, 0, 128);

    memset(&dst, 0, sizeof(dst));
    dst.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dst.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("255.255.255.255");
    dst.sin_port = htons(67);

    memset(&src,0,sizeof(src));
    src.sin_family = AF_INET;
    src.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("0.0.0.0");
    src.sin_port = htons(68);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0)
        perror("Failed to create socket");

    tmp = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &tmp, sizeof(tmp)) < 0)
        perror("SO_BROADCAST failed");

    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &tmp, sizeof(tmp)) < 0)
        perror("SO_REUSEADDR failed");

    if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_FREEBIND, &tmp, sizeof(tmp)) < 0)
        perror("IP_FREEBIND failed");

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth1", sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));

    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, (void *)&ifr, sizeof(ifr)) < 0)
        perror("SO_BINDTODEVICE failed");

    if (bind(sock, (const struct sockaddr*)&src, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0)
        perror("bind failed");

    if (connect(sock, (const struct sockaddr*)&dst, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0)
        perror("bind failed");

    if (write(sock, payload, 128) < 0 )
        perror("Write failed");

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is the the source address is only set to 0.0.0.0 if no interfaces has an IPv4 address. If just one interface has an IPv4 address, this address is used as source address.

I have looked at the source code of some of the existing DHCP clients, and found that they are using RAW sockets and building the IP and UDP header manually. This is possibility, but I would like to avoid doing this manually.

Comment: If no interface has an IPv4 address, you cannot sent the packet at all...

Comment: @glglgl how would you send a DHCP discover then (that needs exactly this)?

Comment: Probably using RAW sockets...

Comment: Ah, your comment was on DGRAM sockets, I thought you meant it in general, makes sense now :)

Comment: @ALlan: Any specific reason to why you are trying to avoid using RAW SOCKET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use RAW SOCKET and construct packet with your own efforts.

As an example you can take this: https://github.com/fycth/DHCP-server-scanner/blob/master/src/dhcpd-detector.c

This is my educational project. It is small and you can look how exactly this task is solved there.

Comment: This is what I tried to avoid... But I guess there is no other way of doing this.

Comment: Sorry for disappointing but it seems there are no way to avoid this exciting experience...

Comment: Unfortunately, even this doesn't seem to work. For raw sockets, a source address of 0.0.0.0 is considered "zero" and is filled in with another arbitrary IP address "helpfully" by the Linux kernel: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html

An option might be to use raw ethernet frames to avoid this, but that has its own drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I think if it was possible to do it via UDP sockets, they would do it instead of building one manually. So I'd suppose it doesn't work at all...